# Consume WebAPI that uses Windows Authentication with Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, blazor, windows-authentication, webassembly, webapi

I am searching for hours now. I have a C# Blazor WASM SPA which get its data from a C# WebAPI (netcore 3.1). For authentication I use JWT at the moment.

I want to switch to a SSO-Solution. Since everything is running in company network, I would like to use Windows Authentication.

I managed to set up the API on IIS for Windows Authentication. But I am really stuck with the Blazor App...

I tried to set it up on IIS with WinAuth/Anonym and to use a simple GET-Request for Login, hoping that NTLM negotiation would pass the credentials from the browser to the API. Would be fine for me, if all further requests would use JWT. Even better if everything would work with WinAuth.

But whatever I try, I won't work. Does anybody has a tutorial or a least a concept I could use for the start?

Comment: What does it mean "won't work"? What exactly happens?

Comment: Won't work meens, that the API always returns a 400 Bad Request when the call comes from the Blazor WASM App. Even the Browser asked me for the windows credentials before. 

When I try to call the API via swagger the browser wants me to enter windows credentials and API calls work fine with it.

Comment: Sounds like your webapis are incorrectly exposed. You should get 401 with auth scheme suggestion so that the client could negotiate it. 400 will never work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

This article shows how to secure both a Blazor front-end and .NET Core back-end api.